# iOS auto logout of application

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am wanting to create a timer or something of sorts to auto logout the user after *x* minutes of inactivity. I would like to do it the same way the Bank of America application does it. The way the BofA app does it is even when the application is put into the background it still keeps track of the time. When the time limit is reached a notification will popup stating you are being logged out.

How can this be done without the timer being suspended when the application goes into the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe the simplest thing you can do is register your AppDelegate with the `NSNotificationCenter` to listen for all events from all (or maybe specific) senders.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resetTimer) name:nil object:nil];
```

You need to take care with passing `nil` to the `name` and `object` parameters as you will get a ton of notifications (even some not originating from the application, i.e., memory warnings).  If you know of or have the list of specific event names and/or objects I would observe on those instead.

In your `resetTimer` method, you will simply invalidate the previous timer and create a new one that will call some `logout` method AND set an iVar to the current date/time (i.e.,  `timerStart = [NSDate now];`)

The above steps will take care of your app while it is in the foreground.

When the app is backgrounded, the timers will quit working.  However, when the app returns to the foreground, you can calculate the delta between `[NSDate now]` and your `timerStart` iVar.  If the delta is greater than some interval, you invoke your `logout` method.  If not, you can just call `resetTimer` to start your timers again.

**EDIT**

If you want the backgrounded app to alert that the user is about to be logged out, you can use a `UILocalNotification`.  You can schedule one to alert when the application enters the background.  When the application enters the foreground, you can cancel that notification (and perform the steps I mention above).

Comment: This was my thoughts on how to do it, however it doesn't account for a notification center alert when the user gets timed out while the application is in the background.